# Very Odd Behavior Accessing Screen Dimensions in C# .NET

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am encountering some very odd behavior while attempting to access the system screen dimensions in a C# .NET Console App. What's odd is that I can access '`System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight`' and get a double value that is exactly half of the actual screen height, and I can access '`System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height`' and get a double value that is also exactly half of the actual screen height. Called individually, both returns are wrong... However, if I simply call the SystemParameters screen height and save it to a dummy double variable that I never touch again, the return for the Forms.Screen call **suddenly starts working** correctly and returns an accurate screen height.

```
double dummyH = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
double dummyW = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
double height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
double width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;

Console.WriteLine("System Param Height: " + dummyH);
Console.WriteLine("System Param Width: " + dummyW);
Console.WriteLine("System Screen Height: " + height);
Console.WriteLine("System Screen Width: " + width);
```

Here's a 3 min YouTube Video I posted about this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_HnF8f0GFQ&hd=1

Thank You!

Comment: you have 200% in your settings as scaling, i'm expecting one of them returns the value in pixels and the other returns the value in unscaled pixels

Comment: But accessed separately, both return the same (incorrect) value. It is only when accessed together that one of the values change and become correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not taking into account your monitor DPI scaling. You need to multiply it by that.

Here is how I do it https://github.com/angelsix/fasetto-word/blob/develop/Source/Fasetto.Word/Window/WindowResizer.cs#L219 and here is the long video of me doing it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDOxHx-AMqQ

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! Any clue why one return would become correct after accessing the other??

Comment: Without digging too far, calling a WinForms calls UnsafeNativeMethods.GetSystemMetrics(SM.CXSCREEN) then converts it using Dpi, forcing the unsave native to fetch the screen DPI. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/SystemParameters.cs,3362 Then it caches the converted size. When calling a WPF call from the same app domain I am guessing they end up sharing the unsafe memory and WPF incorrectly pre-applying the cached, scaled value to its results. Don't mix WinForms and WPF in one application